# Boostrap 3/ASP.NET - Rows are getting merged

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have a jumbotron that I've placed in a bootstrap row within a masterpage. Underneath (still within the masterpage) I have a contentplaceholder. In a separate page, I place a row inside of the contentplaceholder that in theory would create a new row underneath the jumbotron row when the page is combined with the masterpage when the website is assembled. However, when I run my website my contentplaceholder row is being placed *within* the jumbotron row! What is going on here?

Masterpage:

```
<div id="parentdiv" class="container">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #991d85; color: white">
                    <div id="pageTitle" />
          </div>
    </div>
          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

Inside the contentplaceholder in X.aspx:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<div class="row" style="background-color:#F5F5F5;">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="loader center-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="loader center-block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="loader center-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is happening when I inspect the code in the running webpage:

[image: Picture from code inspector]

You can see that in the code inspector the contentplaceholder's row is nested inside the jumbotron row. Why is this?

EDIT: Resolved.

The problem was in the line

```
<div id="pageTitle" />
```

My javascript in the header (not shown) was searching for the element and injecting an h1 element inside of it. However, when I changed the line to

```
<h1 id=pageTitle></h1>
```

The error went away.

Answer (score 2):

You gotta change this

```
<div id="pageTitle" />
```

for this

```
<div id="pageTitle"></div>
```

Comment: Are you sure?  It *should* work, unless you are doing something else incorrectly.

Comment: I will not mark this as the answer, as it is not technically correct, but it was on the right track, so I upvoted the answer. The problem was with this line of code. However, adding the end tag to the div element wasn't the solution; I had to change it from being a div to an h1 (my javascript was targeting the pageTitle id to inject HTML). For some reason the element being a div was problematic.